How to calculate the output frequency of 74LS624 VCO
I'm struggling to understand how to calculate the output frequency of the 74LS624 (datasheet) VCO IC, given a particular input control voltage and a fixed capacitor on pins CX1 and CX2.
I've read multiple times the datasheet and probably I'm missing something, but the only hints were the Figures "Output frequency vs Frequency control input voltage" or "Output frequency vs external capacitance". I was probably expecting a formula with C as Vin as variable. Maybe is there in the datasheet but my noob eyes can't see that. Or maybe it is possible to understand that by looking at the logic diagram on page 4.
Either way I'm going to build a simple PCB with the IC, a 220pF capacitor and a variable voltage between 0V and 5V, and measure the output frequency, but I'm wondering if the output frequency is linear with the input voltage applied to the frequency control input (Figure 1 doesn't seems to suggest so), otherwise I would have to make a lot of measurement to get a good picture of how this works.
I'm sorry if the question is dumb but I'm not pratical at all with those ICs.
Also I'd like to note that my goal is not to use a 74LS624 in a new design, I'm rather trying to understand how this works.

They don't provide the formula in this datasheet. They say "Figure 3 and Figure 6 provide all of the required information", so they expect you to take these diagrams and find your operation point graphically. Probably because the behavior isn't quite linear and there is no good approximation which is also simple enough.

Designers of transistor-transistor-logic (TTL) were hobbled by being limited to using only NPN transistors (no PNP). When CMOS was introduced, much more linearity could be designed-in. For example, CD4046 contains a reasonably-linear VCO. Its data sheet describes nicely how input voltage is converted to current that charges/discharges a capacitor via an H-bridge. Both NMOS & PMOS transistors are used.

As Eugene says in his comment, no such formula, just a curve to trace.
The reason might simply be that you typically use VCOs like this in a control loop – e.g. disciplined by a reference quartz oscillator that gets compared to a divided-down version of the VCO, or against the edges of a self-clocked data signal – so exact numbers don't matter.
What matters is the fact that you can build a control loop that adjusts the control voltage to "lock" onto a desired frequency. And for that, you only need to know the rough frequency and the rough slope (\$\delta f/\delta V\$).

otherwise I would have to make a lot of measurement to get a good picture of how this works.

you cannot use this thing to get a very precise frequency. Even if you measure and "calibrate" a lot, the datasheet doesn't tell us anything about long-term stability or stability under changing temperature, and it shows the frequency is quite sensitive to capacitance variations. So you need to assume that "left alone" at any given setting, that thing will drift a lot. General rule: if a datasheet doesn't brag about how stable something is (or have an explicit table entry that bounds variations), it's not more stable than what's specified in the min / max entries of some parameter. Gotta live with that!
(Living with things drifting over time, temperature and load is a constant endeavour in anything analog; it's why amplifiers are better with feedback, why UARTs only work on short symbols, and why your buck converter needs an "FB" pin.)

Either way I'm going to build a simple PCB with the IC, a 220pF capacitor and a variable voltage between 0V and 5V, and measure the output frequency, but I'm wondering if the output frequency is linear with the input voltage applied to the frequency control input (Figure 1 doesn't seems to suggest so), otherwise I would have to make a lot of measurement to get a good picture of how this works.

Instead, you'd make a small board using this VCO, and the components needed to build a PLL against some reference oscillator – for example, a decade counter IC (which you use to divide the VCO's output frequency by 1, 2, 3, …), a quartz oscillator (with TTL or CMOS output), and an XOR gate as phase comparator, as well as a passive low-pass filter at the output of that, to convert "phase mismatch" to an analog control voltage for this VCO. That way, you build an arbitrary multiple, but quite precisely so, of the quartz oscillator's frequency.
Of course, as you noted, this is a 1980 IC, and you wouldn't use it in this day and age – you'd simply buy a clock synthesizer, or use the PLL integrated into every midrange microcontroller, or a DDS, or just a PWM unit of your microcontroller or… whatever fits your frequency-generating needs. The frequencies covered by this IC are essentially "trivial" for modern digital electronics, which run at much higher rates.

Notice that there is a pretty wide uncertainty in the output frequency with a given control voltage:

(image source: the datasheet linked by OP)
This indicates errors in the neighborhood of 25-30% are possible at either end of the control range, and presumably at other voltages as well. These errors or uncertainties are likely caused by variability in the device performance due to both operating temperature and manufacturing variability.
So there's no strict formula you could produce that would allow you to accurately predict the frequency of the VCO with a given control voltage.
As other answers and comments have already said, the solution is to use a control loop (typically a phase-locked loop) to automatically adjust the control voltage to match the output frequency to a multiple of the frequency of some more accurate reference (like a crystal oscillator or a GPS 1pps signal).
Another gotcha: You should only use this VCO (with 50 pF at Cext) for frequenciees between 1.5 and 7 MHz, even though the typical curve in Figure 4 of the datasheet shows that typical devices will be able to cover between 1.2 and 9.5 MHz.
